# Make Qt Application Use GTK Theme?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

When I run my Qt application on Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 it doesn't use my GTK theme colours or system font.  Qt Creator has the same issue, but other Qt applications I've tried (XnView MP and qBittorrent) do correctly use my GTK theme.  It therefore appears there is a way to get it to work, but I'm at a loss as to how.

I tried this (even though it should be true by default):

```
QApplication::setDesktopSettingsAware(true);
```

That didn't work, so I tried forcing the style to Fusion with:

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
```

This too had no effect.

How can I make my application work so that it respects the system's GTK theme and system font?

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I came across the same problem, but in Lubuntu 14.04. I have overcome this issue simply using

```
qApp->setStyle(new QProxyStyle());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work for me.